# Problem with rotation sprite in LibGdx. The sprite doesn't rotate

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

When I try to rotate an object around its axis around its axis a sprite of game objects I using the rotate() and setRotation() commands, the sprite does not rotate.

Also, when I try to rotate the actor I using the rotateBy() and setRotation() commands, nothing happens too.

In my project, drawing game objects (actors) occurs via the draw() method in Stage.

I noticed that if I draw an object using the batch.draw(sprite, x, y) method, the object will not rotate.

*code from public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter*

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(sprite, 0, 0);
    sprite.rotate(1);
    batch.end();
}
```

And if I draw an object using the sprite.draw(batch) method, the object rotates calmly.

```
@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    sprite.rotate(1);
    batch.end();
}
```

Perhaps this is the reason for my problem.

Comment: Don't use `batch.draw(sprite, ...)` Use `sprite.draw(batch)`. This is due to an unfortunate design decision to make Sprite extend from TextureRegion. But if you draw it like a TextureRegion, all its position and rotation properties are ignored.

Comment: Also, I recommend not using the Sprite class at all for this reason. It mixes game logic with image assets in a hierarchy instead of through composition. Very strong code smells.

Comment: I don't use sprite.draw(batch) for draw. I use method draw() in class Stage.

Comment: That’s even more reason not to use the Sprite class. Now your Actor and your Sprite class will contain conflicting information about position, scale, and rotation that you must keep synced (redundantly) for it to behave and draw correctly. Use TextureRegion instead of Sprite.

Comment: How will TextureRegion help me rotate the sprite?

Comment: When you draw it, you pass a rotation parameter to the `draw` method.

Comment: How to pass a rotation parameter?

Comment: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-